# How to load h2 database using a static sql file

Tags: spring-boot, h2

How to load h2 database using a static sql file, from src/main/resources/data.sql of my Spring Boot App. I am unable to load the database in the following fashion as its unable to get the data.sql file. I won't be able to get the absolute path as it wouldn't work in a docker container

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:src/main/resources/data.sql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Spring Boot automatically loads SQL from `schema.sql` and `data.sql` files.
You should place these files in `src/main/resources` folder, that's it.
If your h2 db is properly configured it should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The default way of loading schema using static sql file in Spring Boot is to use `schema.sql` in your resources file. That should be enought. You don't need to point to that file from a properties file.

You can read more about that here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you are not expecting to persist data in sql file and you wanted to load content from your `src/main/resources/data.sql` right?

In that case, you can start a in memory DB or file DB. If you wish to persist the datasource you can use,

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/sample
```

If you wish to load some content as the server starts, then please follow this tutorial, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql and also refer to the spring boot documentation, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization

In most cases you can use in memory DB and initialize using `schema.sql` and `data.sql`.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

Comment: No I am expecting to load from a static data.sql file

Comment: Please checkout this example and see if this helps. This uses hibernate and inmemory db and starts based on data.sql
https://github.com/reflexdemon/hibernate-demo